# Uwp Conditional back navigation with a Message Dialog

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, uwp, navigation

I want to ask the user whether they are sure that they wanna move back or not and only move back if they select "Yes", for that I am using a message dialog, but the problem is when I press the back button it moves back and after that the dialog pops up asking whether I want to move back or not.

I checked with break point as soon as **messageDialog.ShowAsync** executes the page moves back.

### Code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SampleConditionalNavigation_BackRequested;
}
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= SampleConditionalNavigation_BackRequested;
}
private async void SampleConditionalNavigation_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true; // I have also tried setting it to false
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to move back?") { Title = "Confirmation" };
    // Add commands and set their callbacks; both buttons use the same callback function instead of inline event handlers
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No"));

    // Set the command that will be invoked by default
    messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
    // Set the command to be invoked when escape is pressed
    messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

    //ShowDialog
    var result = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    if (result.Label == "Yes")
    {
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame?.CanGoBack is true)
        {
                rootFrame?.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 1

even if I comment the code where dialog shows itself the page still navigates back, it seems that **e.Handled = true** is pretty much useless here

Comment: `e.Handled = true` does work and so does your code when I test it in a blank app.

Answer (score 0):

This code is absolutely correct and works perfectly, the issue was that my app had **BackRequested** event in app.xaml.cs as well and that event was executing and navigating back before this method on this page was able to execute. Removing it from app.xaml.cs fixed the issue.